# Does setting 3.1 as the deployment target effects devices with newer firmware?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm still using the 3.1 sdk as the deployment target for many of my apps, and I was wondering if this can effect my users that use the latest iOS version (5.0 or 4.3).

Does setting the 3.1 sdk as the deployment target effects devices with newer firmware? If only have a few 3.1 users anyway, and if it can somehow effect 99% of my users, I rather set the deployment target for 4.2 and above.

I'm still testing with both iOS 4 and 5 devices, but i can't test with all different sdk versions.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment target set into XCode is nearly just informative. You won't generate any compile warning nor errors if you use newer method calls. You won't use the SDK3. You'll be able to use 5.0 calls.

So setting to any version you want as deployment target should be with no effect on your users.